# Bar does not appear for the last item added

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a multiple select that adds items to a list within a table, in the code for that table I inserted a bar to separate the added items, but I didn't want that bar to appear for the last item because it looks ugly on the screen. How do I solve this?

-List image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlCCW.png)

-Code image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l52Ml.png)

```
<td style="text-align: center;">
   @if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.ListTipoPenal.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Value == item.COD_TIPO_PENAL_PRINCIPAL.ToString())?.Text))
          {
            <span> NCI - Não Consta Informação </span>
          }
          else
          {
           foreach (var tipoPenal in item.TipoPenalList)
           {
             var listaString = Model.ListTipoPenal.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Value == tipoPenal.ToString())?.Text.Split("-");
             var listaCodigo = listaString[listaString.Length - 1].Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
             if (listaString.Length == 3)
             {
               <span>@listaString[0] - @listaString[1] - @listaCodigo[0] <strong> @listaCodigo[1] |</strong></span>
             }
             else
             {
              <span>@listaString[0] - @listaCodigo[0] <strong> @listaCodigo[1] 
              <span style="margin-left: 0.3em;margin-right: 0.3em;">|</span></strong></span>
             }
           }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easely hidden the bar with the `visibility: hidden` CSS property.

This may help you if you are working with table: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility

Comment: Maybe you didn't understand my question, but I don't want to hide the bar, I just want the bar not to appear in the last item selected as shown in the image.

Answer (score 0):

Don't render a pipe (bar) within html and add it using css:

```css
td span:after {
  content: '|';
}

td span:last-child:after {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>
      Some text 1
    </span>
      <span>
      Some text 2
    </span>
      <span>
      Some text 3
    </span>
      <span>
      Some text 4
    </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```